# Wanting to insert cshtml inside cshtml in ASP.NET MVC4, similar to usercontrol in webforms

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way to insert re-usable code into a cshtml razor file.  I need to pass in data from the outer loop into the user control.  I took a picture of what I'm trying to do hoping that will make it very clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.RenderPartial(<virtual path to your partial view>, session);
```

where partial view is typed view with the model of `session` type.